How to find easiest Capo placement / transposition?
Often when playing chords the guitar I ask myself if there is an easier transposition to play them?
Do you know of any tools that automatically find the best capo placement and transposition for a given chord sequence?
Because it's really tedious to transpose everything 12 times just to find out of there is a better capo placement that results in easier chords.

Do you have an example of a chord sequence? (I'm mostly looking to see if it is [mostly] diatonic, or if it is "in" several keys)

You would never have to transpose 12 times because by the time you get to the sixth fret with the capo you’ve explored all the permutations in one way or another

It will depend a great deal on which chords are in the song concerned. 3 chord songs will undoubtedly be the easiest to transpose by capo, get onto 4, 5, 6 chords and even the 'easiest' won't translate well. Most people use capos to simply change key, once the chords are known. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

All the easiest open chords except one have roots on open strings. The exception is that the C open chord is easy and the B open chord is not.
So, find the three to five most common chords in the song and look only at capo positions that change the most number of strings to the roots of those chords.
For example, capo 1 gives you F, Bb, Eb, Ab, and Db chords.
You could just make a chart of the open chords for the first three or four capo positions and then check that chart every time you start a song. I think with practice you’ll pretty quickly get faster at finding good capo positions.

Don't know about you, but on the (rare) occasions I resort to capo use, for example on 2nd fret, I still regard the chords as if they're their open (no capo) names, rather than F#, B, E, A, if that makes sense.

@Tim Of course.
